# How to call owlCarousel function after a delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I want to call owlCarousel function after a delay of say 5 sec. i tried doing this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
          $(".demo-slide").owlCarousel();
        },5000);
    });
```

But it is giving me error as

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

I just want to call owlCarousel after a delay. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Just make sure you are adding the required js and css files.                             
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added all the scripts needed (jQuery + Owl Carousel) to the HTML file and that .demo-slide points to the right element (the container that wraps the elements to be added to the carousel).

Also, note that setInterval() will call your function every 5 seconds. To set a delay, use setTimeout() instead.

Edit: Also check if you added "owl-carousel" class to your main container, e.g.:

```
<div class="demo-slide owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="01.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="03.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```